# How to charge a conductor w.r.t ground

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

How to make a **charged conductor** ? (without using friction).
Here is one of the suggestions...
[image]
where a charged conductor is used for creating a field around a conductor, creating induced charge on it..opposite on the other n separating them..but we need two metal balls here... 
Please suggest a method in which just one metal ball is used.. I heard about a method, by grounding it after keeping a it in electric field. Please explain...

Comment: Use a voltage supply and a wire. Is this homework? What did you do to think trough the problem?

Comment: Check simple induction in the following link....http://www.esdjournal.com/techpapr/eosesd/failures/induct.htm

Answer (score 1):

The example you show works because the two spheres are connected. You use the external field to pull charge off one of the spheres onto the other, so one sphere ends up positively charged while the other ends up negatively charged.

Now suppose one of the spheres was the Earth. What happens then is that the external field pulls electrons off the Earth so the Earth ends up positively charged and the remaining sphere ends up negatively charged. Just like before.

This is how grounding the sphere works. If you connect a wire between the sphere and the Earth then you are making an electrical contact between the two so that charge can flow between them. You connect your wire, bring up the external field to induce a charge, then remove the wire. You're left with a charge on the sphere. There's also a change in the charge on the Earth, but the Earth is so big the extra charge is undetectable.

Answer (score 0):

Let us discuss method of grounding you have asked, , for it you have a conductor with positive charge density around, you bring the conductor nearer to one side of neutral conductor, hence there are induce charges on it, when I connect a wire between  the conductor and ground, + charges on induces conductor due to potential difference move to the ground. (earth is so large we assume it s potential to be zero, and adding small charges will not create any change in its potential), and now remove the positive charge conductor and conductor, you get conductor with negative charge density all around.